# odoo php xmlrpc search multiple condition

Tags: php, odoo, xml-rpc

I'm using PHP XMLRPC to create a search product from odoo , the products that I'm tryin to search is based on several conditions:

- Search by name or search by default_code.
- Product must be purchase able and therefore purchase_ok status is
  true.
- Product must be active and therefore active status is true.

Here is a piece of my script, that i've try so far :

```
 $ids            = $models->execute_kw( $db, 
                                               $uid, 
                                               $password,
                                               'product.template', 
                                               'search',  
                                                array( array( array( "|", array('name', 'ilike', $search_value ), array('default_code', 'ilike', $search_value ), array('purchase_ok','=',TRUE),array('active','=',TRUE) ) ) ),  
                                                   array('offset'   => (int) $start , 'limit'    => (int) $limit) );
```

But, this script always fail when I combine two filter condition ( OR and AND ), is there anyone have a workaround for this multiple condition filter.

Update, here is my code

```
$ids = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password, 'product.template', 'search',  
                        array( 
                            array( 
                                    "|", 
                                    "|",
                                    array('name', 'ilike', $search_value ),              
                                    array('default_code', 'ilike', $search_value ), array('purchase_ok','=',TRUE),
                                    array('active','=',TRUE) 
                                ) 
                            ),  
                           array('offset'   => (int) $start , 'limit'    => (int) $limit) );
```

Comment: what do you mean by fail it give a wrong result or an error ?

Comment: it returns an error "DOMAIN_OPERATORS_NEGATION"

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: yes, check my update